# Is it possible to get Street View Images into VRPanoramaView?

Tags: android, google-street-view, virtual-reality, panoramas

I'm trying to load google-Street-View images into a VR-Viewer.
Is it possible to load euirectangular images from StreetView into the 'VRPanoramaView'?
Another solution should be to implement the normal StreetViewViewer with the Cardboard-Button.
Does someone have a solution or any tips?

Comment: were you able to get this done? I'm looking for the same thing